# Random Lottery Number help?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Lottery {

    private int lotteryNumbers[];


    public int [] lotteryPicks() {

        lotteryNumbers = new int[499];
        for (int i = 0; i < lotteryNumbers.length; i++) {
            lotteryNumbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 55) + 1;
        }
     return lotteryNumbers;
}
```

This program (not all methods shown) takes the users input of 6 numbers ( 5 numbers and 1 megaball) and compares them with 6 random numbers generated by the computer to see how likely someone is to win the lottery. My problem is with the lotteryPicks() method. Here's the issue I don't know how to create 6 random numbers n amount of times( say 500 )? So ideally it would generate 6 numbers say 12,14,45,32,25,17 and the next time generate 6 new numbers until there's 500 sets of numbers. Also, can you return in a for-loop? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1) `new int[499]` When you declare an array, you say how many values, not the finishing index. 2) Do you really need to generate all the arrays? Isn't it easier to just generate 6 numbers when you need them?

Comment: What is your min and max for the lottery numbers? Is it 1 to 45? If it is, they the permutation for range to 1 to 45 will be applicable, or you just need 500 combinations from the 2.0397882081197443358640281739903e+46 combinations?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `lotteryNumbers` as a two dimension array with the first dimension indicating which set of numbers you're on, and the second dimension is each one of the six numbers.

```
private int lotteryNumbers[][] = new int[500][6];
```

Yes, you can return inside of a for loop.  Also, you should declare a `Random` variable and invoke `nextInt(..)` instead of the approach you're using now which requires you to cast your result.

Comment: thanks! And to make sure it does 6 random numbers should I do like lotteryNumbers[0] =// randomNumber1, lotteryNumbers[1] = // randomNumber2, etc.....?

Comment: Random RANDOM = new Random();
lotteryNumbers[i][j] = RANDOM.nextInt(55) + 1

Answer (score 1):

Your simple `(Math.random() * 55) + 1` might return `42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42`. Lotteries typically do not allow repetition of the number. (One number per ball, one ball per number; once the ball falls out of the tumbler, that number cannot recur.) You should instead generate an array of your 55 numbers, *randomly reorder the array*, and then select the first six elements from the array.

There are two common [shuffling algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Shuffling_algorithms), one that simply decorates each number with a random number, sorts on that random number, and then removes the random number after you're done (a specific instance of a trick known as a *Schwartzian Transform* in Perl circles, *Decorate-Sort-Undecorate* in Python Circles, *`sort_by`* in Ruby circles, etc.). The other algorithm is an excellent choice, but an inexperienced programmer might make subtle but very huge mistakes in implementing it.

> Also, can you return in a for-loop?

Yes, you can, but that is often the indication that the wrong type of loop was used. :)

Sometimes it makes the most sense to return from the middle of a `for` loop, but frequently it makes more sense to re-write to a `while() { }` loop or `do { } while ()` loop instead. When in doubt, try writing both variants and pick whichever one reads the most clearly.

Answer (score 0):

So yo could do what Bala R suggest and return a `List<List<int>>`, where the outer lists holds all 600 "tickets", and the inner list holds the numbers in the ticket.

However, from an object oriented perspective, it would be better to create a Ticket class that contains the 6 numbers, there are many ways to do this -- here's my (pseudo - untested) code:

```
public class Ticket 
{
    private int[] numbers;

    public Ticket()
    {
        numbers = new int[6];

        for(int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
             numbers[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 55) + 1;
        } 
    }

    // Provide some public methods for comparing the ticket and what not
```

}

Then in your main program - you can create a List of 600 (or so) Tickets, ex:

```
public ArrayList<Ticket> generateTickets
{
    ArrayList<Ticket> retVal = new ArrayList<Ticket>();

    for(int i=0; i < TICKETS_TO_GENERATE; i++)
    {
        retVal.add(new Ticket());
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Then when that is done, you use your public methods on the Ticket class to do comparisons/etc.

And to answer your question, you can put a return statement inside a for, it's quite common (ie. when searching an array.)

-- Dan