# C# - checking for duplicates in a lottery program

Tags: c#

I have to write a lottery program which produces 6 numbers between 1 and 40 and checks for duplicates. I have no problem with generating random numbers but it's the algorithm that checks them that I'm having trouble with. Apart from the bugs below, the code seems to work (I have run the program many times and have never gotten any number as a duplicate (except zero, see below).

These are the bugs.

1. I occasionally get two zeroes as the last two numbers.
2. One zero occasionally appears as the last number (but never anywhere else except in bug #1.

Here is the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace LottoV2Program
{
    class LottoV2
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //declare variables
             int[] lottoNumbers = new int[6];
            Random rand = new Random();
            int temp = 0;
            int count = 0;

            //fill array with lottery numbers
             for (int i = 0; i < lottoNumbers.Length; i++)
            {
                temp = rand.Next(1, 41);//generate random number

                 //check to see whether number has already been picked
                while (lottoNumbers.Contains(temp) == false)
                {
                    lottoNumbers[count] = temp;
                    count++;
                }

            }

            //display numbers on screen, one per line
            foreach (int i in lottoNumbers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            //pause
            Console.ReadLine();
        }//end mm
```

Comment: You forgot to post a question.

Comment: _[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_

Comment: Should be there now.

Comment: Change your range of random numbers to a much smaller range and try running your program a few times.

Comment: Add temp = rand.Next(1, 41) in the while so that if a number has already been generated your program generates a new one

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline While he forgot to actually ask something it's obvious he wants to understand his bug.  Alex answered it correctly--there is a question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random Lottery Number help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826909/random-lottery-number-help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have some logic reversed. This:

```
 //check to see whether number has already been picked
 while (lottoNumbers.Contains(temp) == false)
 {
     lottoNumbers[count] = temp;
     count++;
 }
```

will loop, as long as `lottoNumbers` does not contain the value `temp`.

Now imagine, that `i = 3`, `lottoNumbers = { 20, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0 }` and the newly drawn value `temp` is `20`.

In that case `lottoNumbers.Contains(temp) == true`, it will not enter the `while` loop code block, and no value will be added to `lottoNumbers`, but `i` will be incremented. So after 6 iterations (draws), you are left with a `count` that is less than 6 and at least one value of `0` at the end of the `lottoNumbers` array.

You should reverse the logic, so that you keep drawing a number, until you get one that was not yet drawn:

```
temp = rand.Next(1, 41); // generate random number

// check to see whether number has already been picked
while (lottoNumbers.Contains(temp) == true)
    temp = rand.Next(1, 41); // already drawn, try again

// unique number drawn, add it.
lottoNumbers[i] = temp;
```

**Note, for bonus points**

To do this in a statistically responsible manner (i.e. without a large sampling error), you should prevent being able to draw a number twice, by generating all numbers, doing the "Fisher-Yates Shuffle" to randomize their order, and taking the first 6.

```
var rand = new Random();
var lottoNumbers = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 40)              // number 1 - 40
    .OrderBy(x => rand.Next()) // randomly shuffled
    .Take(6)                   // we only need 6
    .ToArray();                // as an array please.
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of checking if the number is already selected, why not doing a list of every number, 1 to 40, then selecting one randomly, when done put it at the end of the list and decrease the random max value.

something like this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int retrieve = 6;
        const int maxNumber = 40;
        const int maxLine = 20;

        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, maxNumber).ToArray();
        var rnd = new Random();
        int[] result = new int[retrieve];
        int pos;

        for (int j = 0; j < maxLine; ++j)
        {
            int number = numbers.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < retrieve; ++i)
            {
                pos = rnd.Next(0, number);
                result[i] = numbers[pos];
                number--;
                numbers[pos] = numbers[number];
                numbers[number] = result[i];
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",result.OrderBy (x => x).Select(x => x.ToString("00")).ToArray()));
        }

        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate a random number
2. If the number has already been generated, back to step one
3. Add the number to the current position and jump to the next

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < lottoNumbers.Length; i++)
       {
           do
           {
               temp = rand.Next(1, 40);
           }
           while (lottoNumbers.Contains(temp));

           lottoNumbers[i] = temp;
       }
   ```

---

A recommendation: your question is not clear and simply saying "this is my code, it haz bugs" is not much... elegant, as to speak. You are mostly welcome to StackOverflow, but please get to know the community a little better. I invite you to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following with a `List` instead of a normal `array`.  You won't get zeroes or any duplicates.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const int MAX_LOTTO_NUMBERS = 6;

        Random r = new Random();
        List<int> lotteryNumbers = new List<int>();

        while (lotteryNumbers.Count < MAX_LOTTO_NUMBERS)
        {
            int lottoNumber = r.Next(1, 41); // Generate random number from 1 - 40
            if (!lotteryNumbers.Contains(lottoNumber))
            {
                lotteryNumbers.Add(lottoNumber);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", lotteryNumbers.ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Results:

> 9, 6, 25, 36, 16, 29

See the code in action here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/EF7Ndc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a C# guy. But the logic is pretty easy to read. I think you are getting zeroes because you are running the loop for lottoNumbers. Length = 6. If there's a duplication you dont perform any action.

example:

- i=0 temp =21 => lottoNumber[0]=21
- i=1 temp =4 => lottoNumber[1]=4
- **i=2 temp =21 => already exist so skip**
- i=3 temp =10 => lottoNumber[2]=21 (notice the array index has not been updated)
- i=4 temp =6 => lottoNumber[3]=6
- i=5 temp =30 => lottoNumber[4]=30

Loop has ended here. lottoNumber[5] is not set. So when you print, the empty array value may be prinitng as 0